# For linear regression: compute $\Theta T X$

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, regression, machine-learning

I have started learning linear regression and the equation $h(X) = \Theta T X$ has puzzled me.

Let's say we have a training set of $m$ and $n$ features such that $X$ is a $m \times n$ matrix. $\Theta$ is a $n \times 1$ matrix, so $\Theta T$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix.

How can we multiply a $1 \times n$ matrix and a $m \times n$ one?

I hope I explained the question clearly. Although this is a very basic question, I am confused. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give some context. Where do you have encoutered the equation $h(X) = \Theta TX$, what are $X$, $\Theta$, $T$ and $h$?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\Theta^T$ (transpose of $\Theta$) rather than $\Theta T$ (product of $\Theta$ and $T$)?

Comment: Are you sure you have the order of the dimensions of these matrices right?

Comment: Yes, it is transpose of Θ. I believe the order of matrices is correct. I encountered this in machine learning class. The linear regression equation explained was h(x)=(transpose of Θ) x.

Answer (score 5):

This question was with respect to linear regression in machine learning class. One of the mentors from my class (Tom Mosher) answered this:

When X is the whole matrix of training examples, then h = X * theta.

When x is a single training example, then h = theta' * x.

Note the use of upper and lower-case letters for x and X.

Thanks @martini and @MPW for your time.